How to delete AWS Managed Grafana workspace?
I'm trying to delete an AWS Managed Grafana workspace from the web console, logged in as the root user. When I try to delete, I get this error:

AccessDeniedException: Your account is not a member of an organization. (Service: AWSSingleSignOn; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: f3cf3630-5e9c-464b-b149-d9164e6e5ccc; Proxy: null)

Indeed, I am not a member of an organization. I don't know why that's relevant here.
The SAML auth was a failed experiment, never fully setup.  I tried removing it via CLI but that fails:
% aws grafana update-workspace-authentication --workspace-id g-61edae3562 --authentication-providers AWS_SSO

An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the UpdateWorkspaceAuthentication operation: Workspace operation failed. Workspace is currently in the DELETION_FAILED state.


